# Getting iron-data-table to render demo data

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, iron-data-table

[When I run my code in this JSbin](http://jsbin.com/hepebapori/1/edit?html,console,output), I expect the `iron-data-table` to render with populated data similar to the way it does [on this demo page](https://saulis.github.io/iron-data-table/demo/index.html). Instead, only the table headers render but the rest of the cells fail to populate.

What changes can be made to the JSbin to achieve the desired behavior?

http://jsbin.com/hepebapori/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>
    <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">

    <link href="https://rawgit.com/saulis/iron-data-table/master/iron-data-table.html" rel="import">

  </head>
  <body>
    <dom-module id="x-foo">
      <template>
        <style>
        </style>
        <paper-button on-tap="msg">Click Me</paper-button>

        <iron-ajax auto
          url="https://saulis.github.io/iron-data-table/demo/users.json" 
          last-response="{{users}}"
          >
        </iron-ajax>
        <iron-data-table selection-enabled items="[[users.results]]">
          <data-table-column name="Picture" width="50px" flex="0">
            <template>
              <img src="[[item.user.picture.thumbnail]]">
            </template>
          </data-table-column>
          <data-table-column name="First Name">
            <template>[[item.user.name.first]]</template>
          </data-table-column>
          <data-table-column name="Last Name">
            <template>[[item.user.name.last]]</template>
          </data-table-column>
          <data-table-column name="Email">
            <template>[[item.user.email]]</template>
          </data-table-column>
        </iron-data-table>

      </template>
      <script>
        (function(){
          'use strict';
          Polymer({
            is: 'x-foo',
            msg: function() {
              console.log('This proves Polymer is working!');
            },
          });
        })();
      </script>
    </dom-module>
    <x-foo></x-foo>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the import of the `iron-data-table`. Just using rawgit won't do the magic, since you need to use a proxy server such as [polygit](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polygit) to make webcomponents work (you're already loading Polymer like this, but not `iron-data-table`).

Due to a mediocre [documentation](https://polygit.org/) it took me a while to figure out, how to combine the polymer import with the `iron-data-table`.

The two configurations needed are `polymer+:master` and `iron-data-table+Saulis+:master`.

Combined, your `base` tag looks like this:

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/iron-data-table+Saulis+:master/components/">
```

With this, you can import the element just like the others:

```
<link rel="import" href="iron-data-table/iron-data-table.html">
```

[Working JSbin](http://jsbin.com/hinonek/17/edit?html,console,output) (Tested in Google Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

To start using iron-data-table in your project you have to:

1. download packages:

> ```
> bower i iron-data-table -S
>
> bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-ajax
> ```

2. create html file referencing those packages:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>     <title></title>
>   <meta charset="utf-8" />
>     <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
>     <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" />
>     <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-data-table/iron-data-table.html">
> </head>
> <body>
>     <template is="dom-bind">
>         <iron-ajax url="data.json" last-response="{{data}}" auto></iron-ajax>
>         <iron-data-table items="[[data]]">
>             <data-table-column name="First Name">
>                 <template>
>                     [[item.name.first]]
>                 </template>
>             </data-table-column>
>             <data-table-column name="Last Name">
>                 <template>
>                     [[item.name.last]]
>                 </template>
>             </data-table-column>
>         </iron-data-table>
>     </template>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

3. create data.json file in the same place where html file is:

> ```
> [
>   {"name": {
>     "title": "miss",
>     "first": "donna",
>     "last": "davis"
>   }},
>   {
>     "name": {
>       "title": "mr",
>       "first": "samuel",
>       "last": "kelley"
>     }
>   },
>   {"name": {
>     "title": "ms",
>     "first": "katie",
>     "last": "butler"
>   }}
> ]
> ```